# How to change font color of command prompt text before $

Tags: docker

I am using the Docker Quickstart terminal on Windows. As I use it, the font for the part before the $ (for example, the 
"User Name@Desktop-0000AAA AAAAA00 ~/Desktop $" part is a color that is difficult to see. The color gets even worse when I try to use devilbox. I do not see any menu options that change these colors, only colors for text typed by me or the background.

I have tried looking in the menu to change text and background color, but I see no option for the text I am having a problem with. I have tried changing the color of the background but the text I have trouble seeing has a black background around it no matter what I change the background to.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you try this website: http://bashrcgenerator.com. It's a graphical UI to help you customize your prompt. You can modify things like text color, background color, and what text is displayed before each command.